# Code stuck when requesting size property of ALAssetRepresentation

Tags: ios, iphone, alassetslibrary, alasset

I have a method that returns the data of an ALAsset. I call this method for one asset after the other to get NSData from them and upload it to a server. After every 4 or 5 calls, the code gets stuck on rep.size call below. When I pause and resume execution in XCode it starts to work again. I am completely stumped, any help would be appreciated.

Clarification: The deadlock/code gets stuck inside the ALAssetsLibrary code, not inside my code.

Additional info: I have just one instance of ALAssetsLibrary and I am making sure it is not being used from any other thread.

```
+(void)getDataFromAssetURL:(NSString *) myImageURL ofType:(enum ImageType)imageType andPerformBlock:(NSDataBlock)block blocking:(BOOL)blocking
{
    NSConditionLock * albumReadLock = nil;
    if (blocking) {

        albumReadLock = [[NSConditionLock alloc] initWithCondition:PENDING];
    }
    @autoreleasepool {
        @try {

            NSURL *str = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: myImageURL];

            ALAsset * asset = [[AppManager sharedInstance].assetObjectCache objectForKey:str];
            if (asset && NO) {
                block( [Util getDataFromAsset:asset ofType:imageType] );

                // notifies the lock that "all tasks are finished"
                [albumReadLock lock];
                [albumReadLock unlockWithCondition:ALLFINISHED];
            }
            else {
                ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
                {
                    @autoreleasepool {
                        @try {


                            [[AppManager sharedInstance].assetObjectCache setObject:myasset forKey:str];

                            NSData * assetData = [Util getDataFromAsset:myasset ofType:imageType];

                            block(assetData);

                            // notifies the lock that "all tasks are finished"
                            [albumReadLock lock];
                            [albumReadLock unlockWithCondition:ALLFINISHED];



                        }
                        @catch (NSException *exception) {
                            block(nil);
                            // important: notifies lock that "all tasks finished" (even though they failed)
                            [albumReadLock lock];
                            [albumReadLock unlockWithCondition:ALLFINISHED];
                        }
                        @finally {

                        }
                    }

                };

                ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
                {
                    block(nil);
                    // important: notifies lock that "all tasks finished" (even though they failed)
                    [albumReadLock lock];
                    [albumReadLock unlockWithCondition:ALLFINISHED];
                };



                if(str)
                {
                    NSURL *asseturl = str;

                    [[AppManager sharedInstance].assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl
                                                               resultBlock:resultblock
                                                              failureBlock:failureblock];

                }
                else {
                    block(nil);
                    // notifies the lock that "all tasks are finished"
                    [albumReadLock lock];
                    [albumReadLock unlockWithCondition:ALLFINISHED];
                }
            }


        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            block(nil);
            // notifies the lock that "all tasks are finished"
            [albumReadLock lock];
            [albumReadLock unlockWithCondition:ALLFINISHED];
        }
        @finally {

        }
    }

    if (blocking) {
        // non-busy wait for the asset read to finish (specifically until the condition is "all finished")
        [albumReadLock lockWhenCondition:ALLFINISHED];
        [albumReadLock unlock];

    }
}


+(NSData *)getDataFromAsset:(ALAsset *)myasset ofType:(enum ImageType)imageType
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];

    CGImageRef iref = nil;
    NSData *assetData = nil;

    if (imageType == FULL_RESOLUTION) {
        Byte *buffer = (Byte*)malloc(rep.size);
        NSUInteger buffered = [rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:rep.size error:nil];
        assetData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];
    }
    else if (imageType == LARGE_IMAGE){
        iref = [rep fullScreenImage];
        UIImage * uiimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        ////NSLog(@"%f %f", uiimage.size.width, uiimage.size.height);
        assetData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uiimage, 1.0f);
    }
    else if (imageType == SQUARE_THUMB){
        iref = [myasset thumbnail];
        assetData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref], 1.0f);
    }
    else if (imageType == PERSPECTIVE_THUMB){
        iref = [myasset aspectRatioThumbnail];
        assetData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref], 1.0f);
    }

    return assetData;
}
```

New information: Turns out the problem only occurs on a specific device. As stated above, if I pause and un-pause the debugger in XCode the code moves forward.

Comment: I don't know yet the solution to that, but I do know that this is a very arcane way of doing it. You need to look into GCD whose one of the main purpose was to reduce this headache of locks. It also makes code much more cleaner and you get a higher level of abstraction. 

Also, you don't need to play with autorelease pools for the most part if you are in ARC environment. As far as debugging deadlocks are concerned, see this: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/324247-debugging-deadlocks.html

Comment: Like I explained in my question, the deadlock comes within the iOS (ALAssetLibrary code), not because of the locks I am using. The locks I am using are only for the purpose of making the function synchronous (which unfortunately is a requirement).
I am updating the question to make it more clear that the deadlock is in the ALAssetLibrary code.

Comment: @try/@catch in Objective-C has a different meaning than in other languages. Simply put, they are just a better Assert. You should assume that your program is in a corrupt state after catching an exception, and the only correct course of action is to abort the program as soon as possible.

Comment: Did you managed to fix it?

Comment: @Devfly yes and no. I tested the same code with another iPhone and it worked fine without a problem every time. I then tried another sample application that accessed the ALAssetLibrary on the first iPhone and was able to reproduce the problem every time. It seems that the photo library of that iPhone was corrupt. I reset that iPhone and restored the photo library and have not seen the problem since.

Answer (score 0):

You will cause a deadlock in the a ALAsset code if you initiate this block of code from the main thread. You must first drop onto a background thread because the ALAssetsLibrary requires the ability to execute code on the main thread, and if the main thread is blocked in the manner that you have outline above then it will be waiting forever to do so.